# How to schedule start of an EC2 instance at a particular time by sending API request to Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to schedule start/stop of an EC2 instance at a particular time by sending API request to an AWS Lambda function. I looked upon myself and found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/) article. Although it explains how we can use cloudformation instance scheduler template to schedule EC2 instances at regular intervals using Lambda, but this is not I wanted to do.

I wanted to create a python script which would send an API request to trigger a lambda function. The API request will contain parameters for EC2 instance ID, a particular date and time at which I want the instance to start/stop, etc. The Lambda function should note the request and automatically start/stop that EC2 instance at the particular time which was mentioned in the request.

Is there a way to do so in AWS?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear how to address your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a **custom solution** for that. A part of this solution could be **one-time cron rule** for [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-schedule-expressions.html) (EB), such as

```
0 2 16 6 ? 2021
```

The EB rule above triggers only once on `Wed, 16 Jun 2021 02:00:00 GMT`.

So your lambda function would have to create such a rule for each instance it wants to stop/start at a particular time. The rule, when **triggered** would invoke other lambda function which would perform the actual stop/start operations. The lambda would have to also delete the rule to clean up your EB. The rules are one-time only, so they should "self-destruct" after being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

> python script which would send an API request to trigger a lambda function.

you don't have to do this. instead, just focus on writing a single lambda function, which will start or stop your instance.

you can use [cloudwatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) or a more recent service [AWS EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/). official [docs on eventbridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html)
i wrote a blog for scheduling lambda with eventbridge, [you can refer that](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/scheduling-lambda-with-aws-eventbridge/)

This should be the keypoints for lambda function :-

1. lets say you invoke lambda at 5 pm to start instance and again invoke lambda at 6 pm to stop instance
2. since its single lambda function use date time module from python, which use conditional logic if its 5 pm then start instance and if its 6 pm use stop instance logic

NOTE:- evenbridge triggers events in GMT, and  Indian Standard Time is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Greenwich Mean Time, just to make you aware.

Also when you want to schedule function event bridge allows you to either schedule in either fixed rate like in every 2 hours or if you want fine granularity use corn expression. this is the website i used to verify my corn expressions [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: But I generate the date and time using some external python application. How would I send the date and time variables to cloudwatch or eventbridge? Using boto3 library?

Comment: i assume you know the time when to trigger your lambda which means it is fixed, hence you dont need to send that to event bridge, in event bridge you will mention your trigger time and write lambda accordingly.like how @marcin posted a rule for event bridge that is how you will trigger event on a fixed time.

Comment: when you want to schedule function event bridge allows you to either schedule in either fixed rate like in every 2 hours or if you want fine granularity use corn expression. this is the website i used to verify  my corn expressions https://crontab.guru/